# How to update remote branch information?

Tags: git

In a git repository, a remote branch I am not tracking was deleted. When I type

```
git branch -r
```

the deleted branch still shows up (and I can check it out)

What git command do I have to run to update this info?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you perform something like

```
git branch -d -r remote_name/branch_name
```

you only remove your local checkout.  This command doesn't do anything to the remote repository, which is why it still shows up.

**Solution:**

```
git push origin :branch_name
```

will remove the the remote branch (note the ':'), and

```
git branch -d branch_name
```

will remove your local checkout.

([Reference](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/02/02/push-and-delete-branches.html))

Comment: You can also run 'git remote prune origin' to clean-up your remote references.

Comment: That will remove all branches that are no longer tracked by the remote repository.  So, just be careful.

Comment: I think it's also useful to know that, although a little bit more verbose, you can use `git push <remote> --delete <branchname>` to delete remote branches, too.

Comment: This usually works, but I cam across a situation today where the remote list wasn't updated, so I was trying to delete a branch that wasn't there.  Thus @Flo 's solution [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17320081/1167442) was required first.

Answer (score 292):

If it were branches in ***remote repository*** that got deleted, and you want to update all local remote-tracking branches at once, you can use

```
$ git remote prune <remotename>
```

to delete all stale remote-tracking branches for a given remote (i.e. those that follow branches which were removed in remote repository).

See [`git remote`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html) documentation.

Comment: Thank you @Casey and @Jakub for your answers! How does it come that the remote branch information stored locally are not updated the next time i use `git fetch`?

Comment: @JJD: Because you might have based your work on remote branch that is no longer here.  It vanishing without requesting was therefore thought to be a bad idea.  That's why you need to explicitely prune remote-tracking branches.

Comment: Does "git gc" clean up stale remote branches too?

Comment: @JamesWald: No, it doesn't.  `git gc` just packs objects and refs, and deletes unreferenced objects while at it (with some safety margin).

Answer (score 194):

```
git remote update --prune
```

Should refresh all remotes' branches, adding new ones and deleting removed ones.

Edit: 
The [remote update](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote.html) command basically fetches the list of branches on the remote.
The `--prune` option will get rid of your *local* remote tracking branches that point to branches that no longer exist on the *remote*.

Comment: This worked for me. I needed to remove a remote branch that for some reason was not able to be removed by the usual 'git push origin :<branch_name>'

Comment: Would it be accurate to say that this answer does what Jakub Narębski's answer does and more? That is, it prunes _and_ it fetches updates?

Answer (score 14):

Also useful for seeing new remote branches:

```
git fetch --all
```

Comment: This helped me a lot.  Some bug in Visual studio git prevents showing the new branches created after cloning. This command helps showing the new branches

Comment: nice n simple thx dude, have a bronze answer badge on the house :)

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the `-r` and `-d` flags to delete remote branches.

Comment: great tip! however, in this case, there are several branches that were already deleted, surely there is a command to fetch these updates

Answer (score 2):

Try this command

```
git gc --prune=now
```